# Using Maven 'exec:exec' with Arguments

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a project configured to build and run with Maven.  The project depends on platform specific native libraries, and I'm using the strategy found [here](http://www.buildanddeploy.com/node/17) to manage those dependencies.

Essentially, the `.dll` or `.so` files for a particular platform are packaged into a jar, and pushed to the Maven server with a classifier identifying the target platform.  The maven-dependency-plugin then unpacks the platform specific jar, and copies the native libraries  to the target folder.

Normally I would use `mvn exec:java` to run a Java program, but `exec:java` runs applications in the same JVM as Maven, which prevents me from modifying the classpath.  Since the native dependencies must be added to the classpath, I am forced to use `mvn exec:exec` instead.  This is the relevant snippet of the pom:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-Djava.library.path=target/lib</argument>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath />
            <argument>com.example.app.MainClass</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

This works fine for the default configuration of the application, but I want to be able to specify some optional parameters at the command line.  Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args="-a <an argument> -b <another argument>"
```

Unfortunately, specifying the `exec.args` variable overwrites the arguments I have in the pom (which are required to set up the classpath and run the application).  Is there a way around this?  What's the best way to specify some optional arguments at the command line without overwriting what I have in the pom?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I managed to find a reasonably elegant solution to my problem using Maven environment variables.

The default values are defined as properties in the pom, and added to the exec plugin as arguments:

```
...
<properties>
    <argumentA>defaultA</argumentA>
    <argumentB>defaultB</argumentB>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-Djava.library.path=${project.build.directory}/lib</argument>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath />
            <argument>com.example.app.MainClass</argument>
            <argument>-a</argument>
            <argument>${argumentA}</argument>
            <argument>-b</argument>
            <argument>${argumentB}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Now I can run with default parameters exactly as I did before:

```
mvn exec:exec
```

And I can easily override the defaults for each argument at the command line using:

```
mvn exec:exec -DargumentA=alternateA -DargumentB=alternateB
```

Comment: And how these arguments can be accessed in Java code, I mean this line: `String[] args`?

Comment: @zygimantus you want `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="path.to.your.class" -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2"` which is out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: @zygimantus yes, the arguments will be inside ```String[] args```

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time understanding the meaning of the tag "<classpath />". Sharing the details for benefit of the community. It adds the dependent libraries which are defined in the pom.xml, to the JVM. For more details, check https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

.... If specified as part of the exec.args argument, the special string %classpath will be replaced by the project classpath as computed by Maven. Same couunts for %modulepath