# How to set both VM Params and Program args using exec-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, jvm-arguments, exec-maven-plugin

I am using exec-maven-plugin to run java app. I need to pass both JVM params and program arguments. I am setting JVM params like this:

```
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>MyId</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>java</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <mainClass>MyClass</mainClass>
                       <arguments>
                           <argument>-XX:+UseG1GC</argument>
                           <argument>-Xms2G</argument>
                           <argument>-Xmx2G</argument>                                    
                       </arguments>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
```

...

and run the program:

```
mvn exec:java@MyId  -Dexec.args="my params"
```

However it looks like arguments set in pom.xml are not used and overwritten by -Dexec.args, and  section is used only as program arguments.

Tried to add  into arguments (as shown in [this article](https://redstack.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/configuring-maven-to-run-your-java-application/)), but ran into

```
Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java for parameter arguments: Cannot store value into array:
ArrayStoreException -> [Help 1]
```

Found similar [unresolved](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-404?_sscc=t) problem on jboss.org.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you opened an issue on the exec-maven-plugin site?

Comment: @khmarbaise it turned out to be a feature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer for my question on the [plugin page](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) - at the very end of it.

> This goal helps you run a Java program within the same VM as Maven.
>
> The goal goes to great length to try to mimic the way the VM works,
>   but there are some small subtle differences. Today all differences
>   come from the way the goal deals with thread management.
>
> Note: The java goal doesn't spawn a new process. **Any VM specific
>   option that you want to pass to the executed class must be passed to
>   the Maven VM using the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable.**

That doesn't work for me, so switching to mvn exec:exec mode.  works for JVM params there.

Found a solution here: [Using Maven 'exec:exec' with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013651/using-maven-execexec-with-arguments)